# "ValueError: initial_value must be specified." error when compiling bert for text classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, huggingface

I'm following the hugging face tutorial for the sequence classification and while trying to fine-tune `'distilbert-base-multilingual-cased'` I'm having the following error when running the model.compile() method.

I'm having the same error when using bert-uncased.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-68f5487774e6> in <module>
----> 1 model.compile(optimizer=optimizer)

/tf/Raph/jupyter/tf2-37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/modeling_tf_utils.py in compile(self, optimizer, loss, metrics, loss_weights, weighted_metrics, run_eagerly, steps_per_execution, **kwargs)
   1035                 run_eagerly=run_eagerly,
   1036                 experimental_steps_per_execution=steps_per_execution,
-> 1037                 **kwargs,
   1038             )
   1039 

/tf/Raph/jupyter/tf2-37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in compile(self, optimizer, loss, metrics, loss_weights, weighted_metrics, run_eagerly, **kwargs)
    547       experimental_steps_per_execution = kwargs.pop(
    548           'experimental_steps_per_execution', 1)
--> 549       self._configure_steps_per_execution(experimental_steps_per_execution)
    550 
    551       # Initializes attrs that are reset each time `compile` is called.

/tf/Raph/jupyter/tf2-37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    455     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    456     try:
--> 457       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    458     finally:
    459       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

/tf/Raph/jupyter/tf2-37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in _configure_steps_per_execution(self, steps_per_execution)
    581         steps_per_execution,
    582         dtype='int64',
--> 583         aggregation=variables.VariableAggregationV2.ONLY_FIRST_REPLICA)
    584 
    585   @property

/tf/Raph/jupyter/tf2-37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py in __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    260       return cls._variable_v1_call(*args, **kwargs)
    261     elif cls is Variable:
--> 262       return cls._variable_v2_call(*args, **kwargs)
    263     else:
    264       return super(VariableMetaclass, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)

/tf/Raph/jupyter/tf2-37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py in _variable_v2_call(cls, initial_value, trainable, validate_shape, caching_device, name, variable_def, dtype, import_scope, constraint, synchronization, aggregation, shape)
    254         synchronization=synchronization,
    255         aggregation=aggregation,
--> 256         shape=shape)
    257 
    258   def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):

/tf/Raph/jupyter/tf2-37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py in getter(**kwargs)
     65 
     66   def getter(**kwargs):
---> 67     return captured_getter(captured_previous, **kwargs)
     68 
     69   return getter

/tf/Raph/jupyter/tf2-37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py in creator(next_creator, **kwargs)
   2855     def creator(next_creator, **kwargs):
   2856       _require_strategy_scope_strategy(strategy)
-> 2857       return next_creator(**kwargs)
   2858 
   2859     self._var_creator_scope = variable_scope.variable_creator_scope(creator)

/tf/Raph/jupyter/tf2-37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py in <lambda>(**kws)
    235                         shape=None):
    236     """Call on Variable class. Useful to force the signature."""
--> 237     previous_getter = lambda **kws: default_variable_creator_v2(None, **kws)
    238     for _, getter in ops.get_default_graph()._variable_creator_stack:  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    239       previous_getter = _make_getter(getter, previous_getter)

/tf/Raph/jupyter/tf2-37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py in default_variable_creator_v2(next_creator, **kwargs)
   2644       synchronization=synchronization,
   2645       aggregation=aggregation,
-> 2646       shape=shape)
   2647 
   2648 

/tf/Raph/jupyter/tf2-37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py in __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    262       return cls._variable_v2_call(*args, **kwargs)
    263     else:
--> 264       return super(VariableMetaclass, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    265 
    266 

/tf/Raph/jupyter/tf2-37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py in __init__(self, initial_value, trainable, collections, validate_shape, caching_device, name, dtype, variable_def, import_scope, constraint, distribute_strategy, synchronization, aggregation, shape)
   1516           aggregation=aggregation,
   1517           shape=shape,
-> 1518           distribute_strategy=distribute_strategy)
   1519 
   1520   def _init_from_args(self,

/tf/Raph/jupyter/tf2-37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py in _init_from_args(self, initial_value, trainable, collections, caching_device, name, dtype, constraint, synchronization, aggregation, distribute_strategy, shape)
   1594             synchronization, aggregation, trainable, name))
   1595     if initial_value is None:
-> 1596       raise ValueError("initial_value must be specified.")
   1597     init_from_fn = callable(initial_value)
   1598 

ValueError: initial_value must be specified.
```

tensorflow version: 2.3.0

transformers version: 4.20.1

python version: 3.7

Any ideas? thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please post the code that is causing this issue (i.e. a minimal reproducible example)?